# How to create X amount of tasks (threads) in every Y seconds in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 1000 RTP streams of 30 sec each that I need to stream to a server, each stream should run on different threads.

For now I am just using a loop in order to create these thread and launch the task, due to initialization delay. I would like to spread a bit the load on the initialization and start between `~3.5-20` threads per second.

What would be the best approach for that ?

Comment: Do you have 1000 processors available?  It might be that 1000 threads on a single processor will be slower than serial processing, because all those threads will time slice each other to death.

Comment: Why do you need a ramp-up?

Comment: _...each stream should run on different threads_  Why?  Creating and destroying threads is _expensive_.  It's much better to have a pool of re-useable _worker threads_ that perform given _tasks_.  Then you could say, "each stream should be run in its own _task_."  Creating and destroying tasks is not inherently more expensive than creating and destroying any other kind of object.  See RobAu's answer and Mikki's answer for more about _thread pools_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) framework and decide which Executor case is the best for you.

Very basic example:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread('' + i);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
```

You probably don't want 1000 simultaneous `Thread`s, but rather a `ThreadPool`.

Also, see the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) if you want to start Threads with a delay or at a schedule.

Comment: It does not come with the ramp-up feature that was asked for here, though.

Comment: Why does OP need a ramp-up? This is almost never really needed.

Comment: Almost never - except in this question, where OP asks for it :-)

Comment: And that's not uncommon. For example, JMeter (and similar load generator tools) have that.

Comment: @RobAu just update the question, i have 1000 RTP streams of 30 sec that i need to run, there for this approach wont help me, i need to have them run in parallel. but to start them in delay (in case the 1000 would be to much i would reduce it to the number that will work fine with the server i have)

Comment: @USer22999299 code above runs 5 threads in parallel. You can increase the size of the fixed thread pool to any number you like. More threads than CPU's will limit your performance if your `Thread` is CPU bound. I guess your problem is bound by the server capacity?

Comment: @RobAu true, at the end i did use the Executors service, as well used a counter and used % with #callPerSecond to have a sleep timer of 1 sec, this trick worked well :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use a threadpool than create individual threads on demand. In Java, thread creation involves time overhead. Threadpools overcome this delay.

> Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide
>   improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous
>   tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a
>   means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads,
>   consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor
>   also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed
>   tasks.

Ref: [JavaOfficialDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

'ExecutorService' is used to execute jobs using the thread pools.This overcomes the thread creation overhead for each invocation

Ref: [http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html]

As well do check out 'ForkJoinPool' introduced in Java7 which has the 'work-stealing' feature, ability of an empty thread to fetch jobs from a busy thread

Ref: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html]